# Why can't an array of enum be used for params Enum[]?

Tags: c#, enums

It seems that for integer, I can either pass an array or comma-separated integers. But for enum, only comma-separated enums work. Why is it so?

```
    enum Animal { Dog, Cat, Mouse};
    void Caller()
    {
        int[] aaa = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Ints(1, 2, 3);
        Ints(aaa);

        Animal[] bbb = { Animal.Dog, Animal.Cat, Animal.Mouse };
        Enums(Animal.Dog, Animal.Cat, Animal.Mouse);
        //CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Animal[]' to 'System.Enum'
        Enums(bbb);
    }

    void Ints(params int[] aaa)
    {
    }

    void Enums(params Enum[] aaa)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Enum` isn't a "real" type that describes an `enum`, because the former is a class and the latter is a plain old integer of some kind (you can describe which kind of integer you want). More accurately, `Enum` is an `enum` boxed.

Note that you can still get full functionality, while keeping your function generic, if you let the compiler construct the correct generic array type:

```
void Enums<TEnum>(params TEnum[] aaa) where TEnum: Enum
{
}
```

Comment: Note, this still lets you write `Enums<Enum>(...)` if you want. If you want to forbid that, and just let `TEnum` by a particular type of enum (rather than `Enum`), you can use `where T : struct, Enum`

Comment: Is it possible to keep the function as it is `void Enums(params Enum[] aaa)`,  and in the caller, somehow convert an array of enums (let's say that the caller got this as its parameter) to comma-separated enums and pass it to the` Enums()` function? I guess it is probably impossible, but I am not sure.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Not without allocating a new array, no. Each element in an `Enum[]` can be a physically different size to each element in an `Animal[]`, and holds different information, so you can't just treat an array of one as if it was an array of the other. You'll have to construct a new array, and turn each `Animal` into an `Enum`. Note also that accepting an `Enum[]` means that each element needs to be boxed, which means a new heap allocation, which is needlessly expensive. @Blindy's answer is the easiest *and cheapest* way to go

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is:

Because, any enumeration inherit from `Enum`, but arrays are covariant, but only for classes, which enums are not. So `Animal[]` does not inherit from `Enum[]`

So, passing enums "argument by argument" leverages inheritance to make the code compile.

Comment: Arrays of **classes** are covariant. `Enum` is a class, not a struct, and `int` and `MyEnum` are structs

Comment: @Charlieface When it comes to CLR _intrinsics_ like `System.Enum`, `System.Delegate`, `System.Array` there's some funky stuff in the type-system that goes on which isn't correctly represented by the CLRs inheritance model, so **as far as I know**, it isn't accurate to say that `System.Array`'s covariance rules for classes apply equally and consistently to `System.Enum` values.

Comment: @Dai `object[] arr = new Enum[5];` works same as any other type. But `object[] arr = new int[5];` does not and neither does `object[] arr = new MyEnum[5];` for the same reason: they are structs. Oddly enough, MSIL will let you (verifiably) do: `MyEnum[] arr = new int[5];` but C# will not.

Answer (score 1):

`Animal` is the type of your enum. The corrected function:

```
void Enums(params Animal [] aaa)
{
}
```

Comment: I want the `Enums()` function to accept any enum type values, not just one type of enum. Is that impossible, then?